# ReactJS: Cannot get the length of a string in component state

Tags: reactjs

I have a little problem. In my function `isLoginOk()` it never enters into the `if`. It enters every time in the `else` even if my string is longer than 1 char.

When I `console.log` before the `if` I can see that my string is longer than 1 yet it doesn't go into the `if`!

Why is that? (I have verified that the string in my component state is correctly updated by `handleChange()`)

```
export default class InputLogin extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        this.state = {
            login: "",
        }
    };

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
        });
    }

    isLoginOk() {
        if (this.state.login.length > 1) {
            return (<div>OK</div>);
        } else {
            return (<div>ERROR</div>);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="login" value={this.state.login} onChange={this.handleChange} /> {this.isLoginOk()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: React is a framework for JavaScript, it doesn't change how JavaScript works. So if `this.state.login.length > 1` is never `true` then you are not setting the value of `this.state.login` correctly. Did you verify that `e.target.name` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Hello,I did it's fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an inconsitency with the way you're setting the component state in `handleChange()` versus the way `isLoginOk()` expects the state to be defined.

In the `handleChange()` function, the "square bracket" syntax `[e.target.value]` means that you're setting the state value for key `[e.target.name]` as an array:

```
 this.setState({
        // Brackets around [e.target.value] creates array value
        [e.target.name]: [e.target.value] 
 });
```

The `isLoginOk()` function however, expects the value to be a string rather than an array:

```
isLoginOk() {

    // You're accessing the string directly and not as an array item
    if (this.state.login.length > 1) {
        return (<div>OK</div>);
    } else {
        return (<div>ERROR</div>);
    }
}
```

Consider revising your `handleChange()` function like so to ensure that the state is updated in a way that is compatible with `isLoginOK()`:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value // Remove the [ and ] around value
    });
}
```

Comment: Good catch! It would be useful to explain what the `[...]` around `e.target.value` mean and why that causes the condition to always fail.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks - I've just updated the answer with a some extra detail and documentation

Comment: Hello, that was the problem.
However my login variable was correctly updated. It's a strange behaviour but you found the problem.
Thanks

Comment: I just did it. I needed 2 min to do so because of my last post ;)
thanks and thx for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your code, in your `handleChange` value.

```
[e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
```

You're setting the value of `this.state.login` to `['some input']`. Your validation always fails because you can't get the length of the string *inside* the array using `this.state.login.length`. Your validation will return either `0` or `1` based on the array length, certainly not what you intended.

To fix this, remove the brackets around `[e.target.value]`.

```js
class InputLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      login: ""
    }
  }
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { login } = this.state;
    const loginResult = login.length > 1 ? "OK" : "ERROR";
    
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="login" value={login} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        {loginResult}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<InputLogin />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/261779/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets around e.target.value

Also simplify the render and get rid of the isLoginOk function. Seems unnecessary.

```
<input type="text" name="login" value={this.state.login} onChange={this.handleChange} /> 
<div>{ this.state.login.length > 1 ? 'OK' : 'ERROR' }</div>
```